# Mapping through elements in Puppeteer js, the class is there but it says false

Tags: puppeteer

I currently have the following html:

```
<div class="j-list-field j-list-field--radio j-list-field--disabled GreenBlue"><label for="input_radio_size_060" aria-hidden="true" class=""><span class="j-list-label-content">06.0</span></label><input name="size"
    aria-label="Size 06.0, out of stock" id="input_radio_size_060" type="radio" disabled="" required="" value="06.0"></div>
<div class="j-list-field j-list-field--radio j-list-field--disabled GreenBlue"><label for="input_radio_size_065" aria-hidden="true" class=""><span class="j-list-label-content">06.5</span></label><input name="size"
    aria-label="Size 06.5, out of stock" id="input_radio_size_065" type="radio" disabled="" required="" value="06.5"></div>
<div class="j-list-field j-list-field--radio GreenBlue"><label for="input_radio_size_085" aria-hidden="true" class=""><span class="j-list-label-content">08.5</span></label><input name="size" aria-label="Size 08.5" id="input_radio_size_085"
    type="radio" required="" value="08.5"></div>
<div class="j-list-field j-list-field--radio GreenBlue"><label for="input_radio_size_090" aria-hidden="true" class=""><span class="j-list-label-content">09.0</span></label><input name="size" aria-label="Size 09.0" id="input_radio_size_090"
    type="radio" required="" value="09.0"></div>
<div class="j-list-field j-list-field--radio GreenBlue"><label for="input_radio_size_095" aria-hidden="true" class=""><span class="j-list-label-content">09.5</span></label><input name="size" aria-label="Size 09.5" id="input_radio_size_095"
    type="radio" required="" value="09.5"></div>
<div class="j-list-field j-list-field--radio GreenBlue"><label for="input_radio_size_100" aria-hidden="true" class=""><span class="j-list-label-content">10.0</span></label><input name="size" aria-label="Size 10.0" id="input_radio_size_100"
    type="radio" required="" value="10.0"></div>
```

I page.$$eval it to loop through each one like so:

```
  const sizeOptions = await page.$$eval(".GreenBlue", optionEls => optionEls.map(option => option.classList.contains(".j-list-field--disabled")));
```

I then console.log my results:

```
  console.log(sizeOptions);
```

I get "false" on all.

I'm wondering why, I"m checking if classList.contains on the element option.  I would expect it to appear true on the ones that contain j-list-field--disabled.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [to the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) you should pass just a class name to `elem.classList.contains`, not a css notation of it. So this should work:

```js
option.classList.contains("j-list-field--disabled")
```